# Can't submit App with Siri-Capability enabled (ITMS-90163)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I am currently trying to submit my app to the app store and the latest update will add siri capabilities to the app. So in the capabilities tab I enabled Siri, but now my app fails iTunes verification (ITMS-90163) and I have no clue what's wrong here.

[image]

The string `com.apple.developer.siri` is part of my entitlements file, but I guess that needs to be there, right?

I already tried the classic -> clean build... didn't help

There is no provisioning profile to choose for the siri-extension, so don't know where to change anything...

Comment: which version of Xcode are you using??

Comment: I am using Xcode 8...

Comment: You need to edit your `provisioning profile` and choose `SiriKit` for it. From the `iPhone Configuration Utility` delete the old. and install new provisioning for your app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to https://developer.apple.com. Select identifier -> tap on your app identifier.

[image]

1. Enable Sirikit from here.
2. regenerate your provision profile and install it.
3. delete DerivedData.
4. clean your project.
5. compile again.

Comment: Thanks!!! I love you! :)
Just disabled SiriKit online, enabled it again, downloaded the profile again... and now it works! YES!!! :)

Comment: Welcome George , where is my bounty ??

Comment: It says "You may award your bounty in 22 hours..."